# Basic understanding of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am doing some assignment and i am not good at understanding pointers. Please help me understand what argument i need to pass to this function.

```
void City::setList(List<City*> *l){list = l;}
```

Comment: If only there was a close reason for "Look at the code, the code tells you everything". (That is, you need to construct a `List` of `*City`s. It's a pointer to a list of pointers to `City` objects.)

Comment: Thnx bro...know it was basic..but got stuck...

Comment: And once you created the List @QPaysTaxes is talking about, you need to take its pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 My original comment totally definitely 100% said that because I didn't miss the `*` or anything nope why would you suggest that (fixed)

Comment: The question is so devoid of context, it is meaningless. You can pass `0` to this function. Does this answer your question? I have no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the definition for `List` (and because Google is case-insensitive), I can't give an exact answer, but you'll want to construct it something like this:

```
List<City*> myList;
```

Then (assuming `List` works like Java's [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)):

```
City c; //Or with constructor, or whatever
myList.add(&c);
```

To call your method:

```
// `d` is some other City
d.setList(&myList);
```

There's one major caveat, though: Unless you created `c` with `new` (which, given the syntax example I used here, you probably didn't), any pointers to it are going to be dangling as soon as `c` goes out of scope. You'll want to make sure you aren't doing that. And if you create it with `new`, you have to be sure to `delete` it later.

Comment: Note: I haven't used C++ in ages, so please call me out on anything I got wrong.

Comment: Well, if you're asking for it - both times when you're passing `*c` and `*myList` you're dereferencing not-a-pointer, you have to do the opposite - address-of operator (`&`). Your uncertainty is also wrong as you'd need `City*` only for arrow or dereference operator e. g. `d->setList...` or `(*d).setList...`

Comment: @LogicStuff See, this is why I wanted people to call me out. I knew I'd forget something. Or two things. Probably more, admittedly. Could you take a look at the new version and see if it's alright?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see `myList` was a pointer, change it to `List<City*> myList;` and you'll got it right.

Comment: @Carlton Beat you to it by 110 seconds, actually.

Comment: Be careful with adding `City c;` to the list. As soon as it goes out of scope, you will have a dangling pointer. This is *not* Java after all.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Nope, it's not! Though at the time, I didn't really know anything other than Java. I've added the caveat. Thanks for pointing it out!